# Alternate casing for a string algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to write a js function that alternates the case based on the following constraints:

For each word, the letters should be in uppercase for odd positions, and in lowercase for even positions. Word can contain letters, numbers, whitespace.

I found some help over internet and was able to write the following function but it works for some inputs but not the others as mentioned below.

```js
function CaPiTaLiZe(s) {
  var chars = s.toLowerCase().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i += 2) {
    chars[i] = chars[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  console.log(chars.join(""))
  return chars.join("");
}

// Giving expected o/p for the following i/p                      
CaPiTaLiZe('Hello') //         ==> 'HeLlo'

CaPiTaLiZe('hello world') //   ==>  'HeLlO WoRlD'

//But it does not give expected output for the following i/p.

CaPiTaLiZe('hello world testing 123') //  ==>   'HeLlO WoRlD TeStInG 123'

CaPiTaLiZe(' Hello World ') //            ==>      ' HeLlO WoRlD '

CaPiTaLiZe(' I will see you in 2wo years') // ==>  ' I WiLl SeE YoU In 2wO YeArS'
```

Note: For each i/p, there's an expected o/p on the right side of the arrow(==>) above.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd don't work fine, because "H" in second is at position 1.

Comment: @theAlexandrian I guess OP is aware about it. The question is how to have same formatting even in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regex to capture words and process using your function to parse individual words.

For demonstration purpose, I have used the regex: `/[a-z0-9]/gi` (*assuming you will have only alphanumeric characters in a word. Please update the regex if you can have other characters as well.*)

Following is a sample:

```js
function toCapitalize(s) {
  var chars = s.toLowerCase().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i += 2) {
    chars[i] = chars[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  return chars.join("");
}

function CaPiTaLiZe(s) {
  var parsedString = s.replace(/[a-z0-9]+/gi, toCapitalize)
  console.log(parsedString)
  return parsedString
}

// Giving expected o/p for the following i/p                      
CaPiTaLiZe('Hello') //         ==> 'HeLlo'
CaPiTaLiZe('hello world') //   ==>  'HeLlO WoRlD'

//But it does not give expected output for the following i/p.
CaPiTaLiZe('hello world testing 123') //  ==>   'HeLlO WoRlD TeStInG 123'
CaPiTaLiZe(' Hello World ') //            ==>      ' HeLlO WoRlD '
CaPiTaLiZe(' I will see you in 2wo years') // ==>  ' I WiLl SeE YoU In 2wO YeArS'
```

Comment: Words have to start with caps

Comment: @charlietfl Updated my answer. Hope it answers the question now.

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed his statement *'for each word'* in the question.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for your help, Is there a pure javascript way that i can deal with this issue rather than using regex??

Comment: regex is a part of Pure JS. You can do something like [31piy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019247/31piy)'s answer, but that would add extra iterations for multiple spaced words.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. This goes through each of the words first, and then uses regular expression to capitalize the alternate characters in the word.

Plus, you don't need to convert to lowercase initially. This will be taken care of by the function itself.

```js
function CaPiTaLiZe(s) {
  var words = s.split(/\s+/);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = replace(words[i]);
  }
  
  console.log(words.join(" "));
  return words.join(" ");
}

function replace(str) {
  let first = true;
  return str.replace(/./g, c => (first = !first) ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase());
}

// Giving expected o/p for the following i/p                      
CaPiTaLiZe('Hello') //         ==> 'HeLlo'
CaPiTaLiZe('hello world') //   ==>  'HeLlO WoRlD'
CaPiTaLiZe('hello world testing 123') //  ==>   'HeLlO WoRlD TeStInG 123'
CaPiTaLiZe(' Hello World ') //            ==>      ' HeLlO WoRlD '
CaPiTaLiZe(' I will see you in 2wo years') // ==>  ' I WiLl SeE YoU In 2wO YeArS'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code was only converting every other char to upper case. This code snippet also converts the other chars to lower case.

```js
function CaPiTaLiZe(s) {
  var chars = s.toLowerCase().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
        chars[i] = chars[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
        chars[i] = chars[i].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  console.log(chars.join(""))
  return chars.join("");
}

// Giving expected o/p for the following i/p                      
CaPiTaLiZe('Hello') //         ==> 'HeLlo'

CaPiTaLiZe('hello world') //   ==>  'HeLlO WoRlD'

//But it does not give expected output for the following i/p.

CaPiTaLiZe('hello world testing 123') //  ==>   'HeLlO WoRlD TeStInG 123'

CaPiTaLiZe(' Hello World ') //            ==>      ' HeLlO WoRlD '

CaPiTaLiZe(' I will see you in 2wo years') // ==>  ' I WiLl SeE YoU In 2wO YeArS'
```

Comment: Please note the last 2 inputs does not give proper output. Also, OP's code is better as there are `n/2` iterations compared to your `n` iterations

Comment: He was converting to lowercase

Comment: @theAlexandrian Thanks for your suggestion but last two o/p are wrong as mentioned above